Power BI query ,not able to upload in system
i have one power BI query where data had been uploaded earlier for 198000 but after some days i want to change the data as new fiscal year comes and upload the data in power BI for about 6000 datasets but now excel data not uploaded in query and stuck .
Below mentioned snapshot for your reference.kindly help
data not uploaded in Bi query
